# SQL (greater and equal) and (lesser or Equal) on datetime

Tags: sql

Ok,  here is a super dumb SQL problem,

This is my Where Statement:

```
WHERE OM_ORDER_DATE >= CONVERT(datetime,'24/5/2020',104)
```

Results of the query:

```
OM_ROWID    OM_ORDER_DATE              
1           2020-05-24 01:19:44.360     
2           2020-05-26 20:29:47.303   
3           2020-05-27 20:36:39.707  
4           2020-06-29 00:00:00.000
```

now if I change my query to

```
WHERE OM_ORDER_DATE >= CONVERT(datetime,'24/5/2020',104) AND OM_ORDER_DATE <= CONVERT(datetime,'24/5/2020',104)
```

I do not get any results, any help is appreciated

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? (Your code is non-standard SQL)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have a time component.  One method is:

```
WHERE OM_ORDER_DATE >= '2020-05-24' AND
      OM_ORDER_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2020-05-24')
```

Or more simply:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, OM_ORDER_DATE) = '2020-05-24'
```

This is also index-safe -- one of the very few cases where a function on a column is also index-compatible.

Comment: The second one was exactly the one I needed:) thanks!